# How Do I Properly Close BottomSheet On Android?

Tags: android, keydown, onkeydown, bottom-sheet

I have a problem on closing the `BottomSheet`, I set the `KeyEvent.Keycode_BACK` and checked if the `BottomSheet` is not open, and is opened. I don't have `Collapse` setting `app: peekHeight = 0dp`only `Expanded`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

            if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                break;
            }else if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN){
                startActivity(new Intent(ShareMainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It work when return `true` but continue to return to my MainActivity as if I don't have `else` statement. I even put `break` on it.

What I am thinking since it WILL closed from the first key press, it should exit the `BottomSheet` first (opened) then at the second press going to my `MainActivity`.

Clicking outside `View` hides the `BottomSheet` and no problem going back to my `MainActivity` .

I tried to trace the error through Debug and it tells me error - does not match byte code.

[image: error]

Comment: You can simply override onBackPressed() if you dont want to support pre-Android 2.0 .onBackPressed() added in API 5

Comment: `source code does not match bytecode.` usually means you edited the code after you installed / started the app. Simply run debug again should fix it.

Comment: @Aravindraj - I have both `OnKeyDown` and `onBackPress` seems both have the same behavior. It will exit my app.